# How to fix 'ball.dx' error while coding a Python game in VS Code?

Tags: python

I put the values of ball.dx and ball.dy at 2. But VS Code says, "Cannot assign member 'dx' for type 'Turtle." I don't know why or how to fix the problem.

I tried to use the turtle.Ball class, but it wasn't defined. The code is like this:

```
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("square")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2
```

Comment: `dx` and `dy` are _calculated_ based on the turtle's heading/direction.  They are read-only attributes.  You cannot assign to them.

Comment: But it states that there are problems because they are not assigned. I don't know how to fix them.

Comment: _But it states that there are problems_ Where does it say that?  You did not share any error message like that...